# Flex creationComplete() not executing for certain machines

Tags: apache-flex, events, flash-builder

I have a creationComplete="myMethod(event)" in my s:Application, and it runs fine on my 3 flex (Flash Builder 4) development machines.  However it is not working on the 2 end user machines I tried it on today!

It is not executing the creationComplete at all, but it is running the application and it seems like all the other code is running fine - with the exception of possibly some other creationComplete code for other components in the app.

On my machines I have tested it under IE 8 and 9, FireFox and Chrome - on all 3 machines.

On these two machines it has the problem on both IE 7 and IE 8.  I even installed FireFox new and it also has the issue.   After installing the latest flash player and deleting all browser history/cookies it still has the problem.

What might cause the creationComplete to not execute?

Update:
  I tried using initialize() and no difference.

However, I believe I found the line of code causing the problem:

```
var isDebug:Boolean = new Error().getStackTrace().search(/:[0-9]+\]$/m) > -1;
```

If I comment that out, it works fine.   Why?  I need that to know if my app is running in development/debug mode or on an end users machine.

Comment: If you look at my answer below, it *is* correct. I discovered during some other exploration today that .getStackTrace() returns **null** in a non-debug environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears (I haven't tested this myself) that you are unable to get the stackTrace of an error in non-debug mode?

That's my assumption from your description of the problem. If this is the case, you could just check if getStackTrace() != null.

EDIT: Confirmed, getStackTrace() returns **null** in a non-debug environment

Comment: Seems to work so far, this is what I used:  isDebug = new Error().getStackTrace() !=null;

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this line throws an exception (that'd be funny, wouldn't it ? ) that you can't catch when in non-debug mode...

Have you tried this :

```
import flash.system.Capabilities;

[...]

var isDebug:Boolean = Capabilities.isDebugger;
```